# does just as well -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

Example:

> Descriptive names can be carried to an extreme, of course. There's no point in naming a form frmUpdateContactInformation if frmUpdateInfo **does just as well**. Long names are more easily misspelled or misread than shorter names, so use your judgment.

Could you please explain the inner workings of this construction to me. Is this something along the lines of *will do*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> just as well

is an idiomatic phrase. In the example, it means "equally well".

This ELU question is a similar topic [*What is the meaning of “just as well” in this context?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107223/what-is-the-meaning-of-just-as-well-in-this-context).

> will do (ex: I was going to buy a BMW, but an Audi **will do**.)

is a bit different. *will do* here means (just) satisfactory, but more likely a secondary choice. So it is different from "equally well".